# Passing toggle open state in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I have a toggle open/close DIV with UL list in it that look like this:

```
<div id="dropdown-1">
        <div class="option-heading">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
                    <h5>Title</h5>      
        </div>
        <div class="option-content">
        <ul class="check_list check_list_show">
             <li><a href="#>Item 1</a><li/>
             <li><a href="#>Item 2</a><li/>
             <li><a href="#>Item 3</a><li/>
        </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

And a JS code is:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".option-content").hide();
            $(".fa-angle-double-up").hide();
            $(".option-heading").click(function(){
                    $(this).next(".option-content").slideToggle(500);
                    $(this).find(".fa-angle-double-up, .fa-angle-double-down").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

Once user selects a link from that list, the same page refresh and a results are displayed on it.
But, that DIV gets automatically closed and i would need it to stay open.

I am not a JS developer and i dont have any ideas on how to pass the open state of this after a refresh.Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bumL495j/

Comment: Maintain toggle state in localstorage and read it on page load.

Comment: Sadly, i am an JS newbie and i barely managed to make this one work, everything beyond that is out of my league. Isnt there any easier way on passing the state?

Answer (score 0):

pass a query string in url (i. anchor tag) lik

```
<li><a href="link.html?menutoggle=open">Item 1</a><li/>

 $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".option-content").hide();
            $(".fa-angle-double-up").hide();

             var urlstring = window.location.href; // check for menu toggle you can pass itemid also based on that you can highlight menus
             if(urlstring.indexOf("menutoggle=open")>0){
                  $(this).next(".option-content").slideToggle(500);
                    $(this).find(".fa-angle-double-up, .fa-angle-double-down").toggle();
             }

        });
```

you need to paste this script in every page of that menu items links. i didn't know about localstorage but you can also google for it.

Comment: This is not the only toggle DIV that i have, so it would a bit messy solution